# HTML5 Canvas set canvas position values not parsing

Tags: html, canvas

I am playing around with canvas. I have created three canvas elements and can position the first two fine, however the third canvas element is not accepting the style.top and style.left values.

Any help or ideas or would be much appreciated!

The relevant code, which is in a js file:

```
var setPlayerBoardSize = function () {
    "use strict";
    playerBoard.width = window.innerWidth;
    playerBoard.height = window.innerHeight / 6;
}

var setPlayerBoardPosition = function () {
    "use strict";
    playerBoard.style.top = window.innerHeight / 2 + playerBoard.height;
    playerBoard.style.left = window.innerWidth / 2 - playerBoard.width / 2;
    playerBoard.style.position = "absolute";
```

The console output in Firefox Inspector:

```
Error in parsing value for ‘top’.  Declaration dropped. 
Error in parsing value for ‘left’.  Declaration dropped.
```

The other canvas elements are positioned as follows:

```
var setCanvasSize = function () {
    "use strict";
    pageCanvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    pageCanvas.height = window.innerHeight;
};

var setCanvasPosition = function () {
    "use strict";
    pageCanvas.style.top = window.innerHeight / 2 - pageCanvas.height / 2;
    pageCanvas.style.left = window.innerWidth / 2 - pageCanvas.width / 2;
    pageCanvas.style.position = "absolute";
};

var setScoreBoardPosition = function () {
    "use strict";
    scoreBoard.style.top = window.innerHeight / 2 - pageCanvas.height / 2;
    scoreBoard.style.left = window.innerWidth / 2 + pageCanvas.width / 4;
    scoreBoard.style.position = "absolute";
}
```

They are all declared at the beginning of the page:

```
var pageCanvas = document.getElementById("pageCanvas");
    var pctx = pageCanvas.getContext('2d');

var scoreBoard = document.getElementById("scoreCanvas");
    var bctx = scoreBoard.getContext('2d');

var playerBoard = document.getElementById("playerCanvas");
    var sctx = playerBoard.getContext('2d');
```

The canvas declarations in the HTML file is:

```
<canvas id="sparkyCanvas" width="1000" height="600">      
    </canvas>
<canvas id="scoreCanvas" width="300" height="100">        
    </canvas>
<canvas id="playerCanvas" width="1000" height="100">
    </canvas>
```

I'm stumped! Any help would be welcomed.

Comment: Please share your html code as well

Comment: I've edited the question to include the canvas declarations. The canvas code all works, the page loads as intended and draws specified objects on each canvas, however the playerCanvas won't accept my style.top and style.left values to be able to position it where I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS positions values require units. `someElement.style.position.left = 123` has no meaning in CSS. It's 123 of what? `px`, `em`, `%` ...

```
    function px(v) {
      return (v | 0) + 'px';
    }

    pageCanvas.style.top = px(window.innerHeight / 2 - pageCanvas.height / 2);
    pageCanvas.style.left = px(window.innerWidth / 2 - pageCanvas.width / 2);
```

etc...

The only exception is `0`.  `0` needs no units. For example

```
margin: 0;
```

or

```
style.margin = 0;
```

is valid.

Comment: Then again, you may just be a genius (please forgive my impertinence)!. That's got it, many thanks!